# OpenCL/OpenGL Interop on ARM

Tags: c++, opengl, arm, opencl

i have a small problem with OpenCL/OpenGL interoperability in my code

here's my makefile

```
LIBS = -lm -lOpenCL -lGAL -lGLEW -lglut -lGLU -lpthread
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
OBJECTS = main.o environment.o input.o animate.o buddhabrot.o buddhacl.o cmodules/timer.o
all: prognonmpi
prognonmpi: $(OBJECTS)
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/ c++ $(CFLAGS) -o prognonmpi $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
%.o: %.cpp $(LIBS)
clean:
rm -f *.o prog cmodules/*.o
```

the code just comiles fine, but i get a linker error with the following message

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/ c++ -Wall -g -o prognonmpi main.o environment.o input.o animate.o buddhabrot.o buddhacl.o cmodules/timer.o -lm -lOpenCL -lGAL -lGLEW -lglut -lGLU -lpthread
main.o: In function `displayFunc()':
main.cpp:(.text+0xdda): undefined reference to `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects'
main.cpp:(.text+0xe12): undefined reference to `clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects'
main.o: In function `initOpenGLBuffers(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x136a): undefined reference to `clCreateFromGLBuffer'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [prognonmpi] Error 1
```

the code compiles very fine on my notebook with the lins, using -lGL instead of -lGAL, seesm -lGAL is ARM specific.

on the ARM machine i get the above mentioned error.
Any suggestions what is missing on my ARM-machine?
using Ubuntu as OS

Comment: Seems no OpenGL-OpenCL interoperability is enabled. Maybe you have to enable it trough a define or extension.

Comment: this was my thought too, but why does it then comile fine on a x86_64 and not on arm with the same code?

Comment: I work with OpenCL in ARM, and I know that we've been working on GL/CL interop functionality. Have you read the release notes to see what it says for your release? (Also, which OpenCL implementation is it - ARM or for example Broadcom or Qualcomm?)

Comment: the implementation is from Freescale, for the i.MX6

Comment: fixxed. patched the error reporting functions

Comment: this api is part of cl_gl.h. OpenCL implementations can choose to ignore support for this api as its not compulsory. Verify it by readelf -s /path/to/libopencl/so |grep -i clEnqueueAcquire  . probably your .so doesn't have this symbol! it works on x86_64 because amd/intel/nvidia has complete support for this function. Ask your vendor